# catkin_make looking for src/src/

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am new about ros and c++.

I am doing some school project with raspberry pi3 and ros. My professor recommend this.
I install the ros kinetic based on ubuntu mate. I try to install the hokuyo laser which is I only got for slam.

I am downloading the source and try to `catkin_make` in my `src` folder.(is it right?)
However they are showing this.

The specified source space `/home/kangr/ros_catkin_ws/src/src` does not exist

I have no idea what i have to do. please help me.

```
kangr@kangr:~/ros_catkin_ws$ ls
build  devel  src
kangr@kangr:~/ros_catkin_ws$ cd src
kangr@kangr:~/ros_catkin_ws/src$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  driver_common  urg_node
kangr@kangr:~/ros_catkin_ws/src$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/kangr/ros_catkin_ws/src
The specified source space "/home/kangr/ros_catkin_ws/src/src" does not exist
```

env:

```
kangr@kangr:~/ros_catkin_ws/src$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/kangr/ros_catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/kangr/ros_catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246537/catkin_make-looking-for-src/src//) by [donghok4](https://answers.ros.org/users/28353/donghok4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-27**:
If you're really just starting out, I recommend you pick up one of the books about ROS. One that I've heard is good for beginners is [A Gentle Introduction to ROS](https://cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/). You can buy a copy of Amazon, or download it from the website. Support the author, buy a copy.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-27**:
If you're more of a video person: try [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9U6GDonGFHw).

**Comment by [donghok4](https://answers.ros.org/users/28353/donghok4/) on 2016-10-31**:
Thanks I will read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

go to /home/kangr/ros_catkin_ws directory, and catkin_make there

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-27**:
This is the answer.

@donghok4: the error message would seem to tell you this as well: is there a directory `src` inside your `/home/kangr/ros_catkin_ws/src` directory?